# Probability. (Independent Events)

Tags: probability

The probability that a person in a particular evening class is left-handed is $\frac{1}{6}$. From a class of 15 women and 5 men a person is chosen at random. Assuming the 'left-handedness' is independent of the sex of a person, find the probability that the person chosen is a man or is left-handed.

Can anyone give some hints to me?

Comment: What is the expected number of right-handed women?

Comment: Hint: independent $\implies P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of independent events?

Answer (score 1):

$P$(man) OR $P$(left-handed)

$$=\dfrac5{15+5}+\dfrac16-\dfrac5{15+5}\cdot\dfrac16$$

Comment: Should be 15+5 .

Comment: @Mathxx, Thanks, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

$P(M\vee L)=1-P(M^c\wedge L^c)=\dots$ use independency here.